# How to Print json data using multiselect.js drop down with angular js

Tags: angularjs

How to print my json data inside users drop down (user-friendlier drop-in replacement using multiselect.js with angular js)

My Json Data like this :

```
[{"name":"Test Test","user_id":"21"},{"name":"fname staff lname stadd","user_id":"22"},{"name":"client new name lname client","user_id":"24"},{"name":"manish sharma","user_id":"25"}]
```

My HTML Code :

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="status" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Users</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select multiple="multiple" id="multiselect" multiselect name="users_id" ng-model="memo_FormData.users_id">
        <option ng-repeat="option in list_users" value="{{option.user_id}}" ng-bind="option.name"></option>

      </select>
      </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: nice question.. have you found any solution on this ? if so please update your answer with your suggestion/solution (if any).

Comment: yes i found the solution , please give me some time so i update it.

Comment: Great!!! looking forward (y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution

declare blank array inside your function in angular controller

```
 $scope.get_group_users = function()
      {

            $scope.list_users = [];
    /*this is my factory as well as function*/  
         groupFactory.group_wise_get_users_list().success(function(data,status,headers){

                  $scope.list_users = data;

            }).error(function(data,status,header,config){}); 

      }
```